# Is ninject considered a container?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, ninject

I was talking with someone and mentioned I was learning IOC and was using ninject to get the feel for things.

He asked me what container I was using?  I told him ninject.

Having no idea what he was referring to, I know there is castle windsor products that are more popular.

Can someone clear this up for me? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [Ninject](http://ninject.org/) is an IoC/DI Container framework/library.

There's a [great post by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx) that lists many of the .NET DI Container libraries. See also [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) for an explanation of containers (injectors).